# Set UI elements on equidistant points on circumference of an ellipse using XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm making an analog clock-like app and I need the numbers (represented by buttons) on my clock face to be at equidistant points from one another. Is there a way to identify the specific ponts and the distances between them on the ellipse and then place the UI elements centered on the appropriate points? I have a feeling I would need to use a Canvas for this but the logic for its implementation evades me.

In other words, how do I place buttons or other controls on certain equidistant points along a predefined geometry so that they are anchored to those points?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2006/04/070132.html

Here is an all XAML clock by the great Charles Petzold

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29438/Analog-Clock-in-WPF

And here is another solution in WPF which should be easily portable

Comment: Thanks, but not quite what I was looking for. Will have to rephrase my question.

Comment: You should accept @RajeevBhatia 's answer ... the solution to your problem is embedded in Petzold's All XAML Clock. Where he draws 12 smaller ellipses around the circumference of one larger ellipse, you'd place 12 buttons.